# Xcode and iOS5.1 on iPhone won't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios5.1

Did I miss something? I updated my iPhone to 5.1 and now Xcode won't install developer apps on it. Here's from the Organizer:

OS Installed on User's iPhone
5.1 (9B179)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2

Comment: I am debugging using XCode4.2 (on snow leopard) on my upgraded iOS 5.1 device, following instructions from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-for-ios-development)

Comment: For all who despair without hope. I found hope today and spreading the love :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611596/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-and-retina-in-ipad-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current Xcode doesn't have the latest iOS 5.1 SDK (not to mention it looks like Apple took down the beta builds). You'll have to wait until Apple updates Xcode.

Comment: Sadly, my guess is that they're only updating to include the iOS SDK and maybe a couple quick fixes, but nothing too major.

Comment: Update now available, you called it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to download Xcode 4.3.1, but they try to force it through the app store and a lot of people are having problems with it.  If you want to get the download directly, go to Xcode section of the iOS dev center:  https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php

1. Don't click the "View in Mac App Store" button - instead click the link at the bottom that reads: Looking for additional developer tools? View Downloads
2. Log in.  Unfortunately, paid members only.
3. The 3rd or 4th item on the list will be Xcode 4.3.1 for Lion.  You can download the DMG there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have snow leopard, I will eventually move to lion but for the time being can I revert back my iPhone to iOS 5?

Comment: You could try restoring from backup through iTunes, but I have no idea if that will work.  You should just go ahead and move to Lion.  I avoided it for a long time, but I made the jump and things have stabilized quite a bit.  Good luck!

Comment: I have downloaded xcode 4.3 then copied ios5.1 sdk to my xcode 4.2. it worked fine.