# iOS 5.1 with Xcode 4.2 and retina in iPad 3

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina-display

i have a Mac with Mac OS X Snow Leopard, can i add iOS 5.1 to it?

With the new resolution for iPad 3, how we will do with images, because if the app will run in iPhone 3GS, 4 and iPad 3 i think we should have 3 images with different name like @3x.png or ..
thank you.

Comment: this below two links will provide the details [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

iOS 5.1 comes with Xcode 4.3.1 which is only available for Lion — the only download available in the Developer section on Apple's Developer portal for iOS 5.1.

Basically, the iPad images are going to be double the size of the image you would normally create for the iPad. For instance:

> ### Launch images
>
> **iPhone:**  : 320 x 480
>
> **iPhone @2x:** 640 x 960
>
> **iPad:** 768 x 1004 (portrait), 1024 x 748 (landscape)
>
> **iPad @2x:** 1536 x 2008 (portrait), 2048 x 1496 (landscape)

### Per Apple

> **Get your app ready for the new iPad.**
>
> To ensure your iOS 5 apps are optimized for the new iPad, review the updated iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.
>
> - [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
> - [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

### iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 5.1

> With this software you can develop applications that run on iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch running iOS 5.1. You can also test your applications using the included iOS Simulator, which supports iOS 5.1. **iOS SDK 5.1 requires a Macintosh computer running OS X 10.7 (Lion).**

### Naming Scheme:

This seems to be the naming scheme for the new retina graphics for the new iPad.

> **icon@2x~iphone.png; icon@2x~ipad.png**

Comment: The launch images from the iPad 3 are 1536x2048 in portrait and 2048x1536 in landscape. My source is in Xcode 4.3.1 the tooltip from the launch images slots.

Comment: The above info was taken directly from Apple docs. I *(along with the rest of the world)* do not have "The new iPad" yet, so this is untested.

Comment: The difference between the two sets of dimensions that you provided is simply whether or not you include the status bar area in your launch image dimensions.

Comment: Yes, but these are the dimensions Apple documented. So as an iOS developer, you need to compensate for that extra space.

Comment: I can't seem to get the Icons working :S I've tried icon@2x~ipad.png, Icon@2x~ipad.png and Icon-72@2x.png. And I've always made sure they are in the info.plist. Anyone else having trouble with it?

Comment: @Yar what does that have to do with images?

Comment: @Nixarn you have to use xcode 4.3.1 and link against the 5.1 SDK.
from [here](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/03/19/updating-for-ipad-retina-display/#more-1235)

Comment: @nixam: I always drag in images through the project editors summary pane.  Drag them in from outside the app, it will copy and name them as it desires.

Answer (score 43):

@WrightCS's answer handles the part about the images perfectly well.

However, you **can** get the simulator and SDK to run on Snow Leopard.

1. Download Xcode version 4.3.1 bypassing the AppStore from here http://developer.apple.com/downloads
2. Open up the package and copy

   ```
   /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develop‌​er/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
   to 
   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
   ```
3. Copy

   ```
   /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceS‌​upport/5.1
   to
   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176
   ```
4. Copy

   ```
   /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/‌​Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
   to 
   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1‌​.sdk
   ```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649396/8047).

**Edit:** Get your iPad Retina on by copying

```
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
to
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app`
```

Comment: Does this still make the App Store happy in terms of actually using the 2x graphics for the retina iPad? I wonder if they're doing a "built with XCode 4.3.1 or higher" check on the binary (if possible) before enabling retina.

Comment: its work perfectly, but i dont have the ipad retina simulator, can i have it ?

Comment: @MalekRadhouani fixed answer to include the iPad Retina

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but in XCode IDE there are two same iOS devices in the Scheme.

Comment: Great information! Thanks! However, using the newest iPhone Simulator.app from Xcode 4.3 in Xcode 4.2 makes the iPad Retina display GIGANTIC, so I can only see about one quarter of it on my monitor! Any ideas?

Comment: @jsherk hit command 1, command 2 or command 3. Then buy a bigger monitor ;)

Comment: @psychotik Yes just submitted and was approved in App Store with binaries compiled in Snow Leopard against 5.1 API.

Comment: Please also see the answer below from @Kay Röpke which shows how to do the docset

Comment: Probably the best answer on SO regarding latest IOS on Snow Leopard. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You will probably also want to copy the 5.1 docset to be able to view the most recent documentation within Xcode:

Copy

```
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.docset
to
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.docset
```

And be sure to restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 4 resolutions most likely for some items and 2 for others.

1- iPhone
2- iPhone Retina (@2x.png files)

You only need these if you're scaling up the resolution if the old graphic for retina iPhone works you probably want to use that for your iPad UI. Specifics like app icons are a different beast and you will need 4.

3- iPad
4- iPad Retina (@2x.png files)