# Do I have to upgrade to Lion to test on iPad with iOS 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, osx-lion, upgrade

I recently just updated my work's iOS to 5.1.  When I click run in Xcode 4.2, I get this error:

[image]

The selected scheme is my iOS device.

I am currently running Snow Leopard here, and after checking the portal I cannot run the latest Xcode unless I upgrade to Lion.

[image]

Is there any way I can test my app on this device without upgrading to Lion?

Comment: i dnt think so, i updated my mac 2days ago for the same reason

Comment: If you have a developer account, there's a workaround at https://devforums.apple.com/message/630144#630144 (message 19, page 1 of that thread)

Comment: You do NOT need to upgrade to Lion ... you can copy the SDK's and Simulators into your existing Xcode version. See these posts:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31412/how-can-i-install-iphone-simulator-4-2-on-xcode-4-2

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611596/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-and-retina-in-ipad-3

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios 5.1 with xcode 4.2 for iOS development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-2-for-ios-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, you need to upgrade.

Some people have gone to heroic lengths to get SW to run on unsupported OS releases.  Here's an example for getting iBooks Author onto Snow Leopard:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/20/install-ibooks-author-on-mac-os-x-10-6-8-snow-leopard/

In theory, it may be possible to run Xcode 4.3.1 on Snow Leopard or even jam iOS 5.1 support into Xcode 4.2.  In practice, good luck.  I would never personally do it, because development is hard enough.  If Xcode or your app crashes or has issues, you have to throw out all your assumptions.

You mentioned that it is your work's iDevice.  Consider getting them to upgrade your Mac OS or your hardware for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5.1 on a device, then Xcode needs to have the iOS SDK 5.1 installed in order for Xcode to run the app on that device.

If the device has 5.1 installed, and the latest SDK installed in Xcode is 5.0.1, then you will get this error.

Comment: Can/Should I downgrade my iOS? What's weird is that I just made an archive of another app and it built and ran fine.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without jailbreaking.

Comment: 5.0+ is not downgradable (not even for jailbroken users)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Xcode 4.2 with the highest SDK of 5.0 (9A334) and I can compile fine to my iPhone 4s running iOS 5.1 and my iPad 1 running iOS 5.1. I have just connected a new iPad 3 running 5.1 and Xcode says I need to upgrade to SDK 5.1. I went on a wild goose chase on this a few weeks ago after upgrading my 4s to 5.1 from 5.0.1 and installed Lion (which I detest) in a separate partition. After loads of messing around I ended up going back to Snow Leopard and the 4s running 5.1 magically worked. I do not have SDK 5.1 on the system and Base SDK in Xcode shows Latest iOS (iOS 5.0). Therefore it is NOT necessary to have SDK 5.1 in order to compile for 5.0 and run on a 5.1 device.

UPDATE 6-April-12

An update on this. I have just booted into Lion, opened Xcode, the iPad3 is recognised, re-booted back into Snow Leopard, and now I can compile to the iPad3 using Xcode 4.2 on SL. I did absolutely nothing in Lion except for opening an old project and clicking on the iPad3 in the sidebar of the Devices tab in the Organizer.